# Is casting a const char array to an integer in the header always safe?

Tags: c++, standards, standards-compliance

Ignoring how repulsive and hacky it is, is the following guaranteed to be safe? If not, why?

```
//.h
struct foo
{
 const static intptr_t KEY = (intptr_t) "VALUE";
};

//.cpp
void useFoo()
{
 const char * value = (const char *) foo::KEY;
 printf("%s",value);
}
```

Comment: Curious, why would you want to do this?

Comment: As a poor man's way to initialize a const static string in the header. Until c++0x, you could only initialize integral types in the header. You could use #define, or you could initialize the string in the .cpp. I was wondering if this was another way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Not only is the code not guaranteed to be safe, the code is ill-formed.

`"VALUE"` is of type `char const[6]`, which cannot be converted to `intptr_t` via `static_cast`.

Comment: I used the wrong type of cast. I was trying to avoid the c-style cast if possible. The spirit of the question is to cast the address of the beginning of a character array literal to an integer in the header then recover it in the .cpp.

Answer (score 2):

It is guaranteed not to compile. You cannot use `static_cast` to convert from pointer to an integral type or viceversa. If it was a `reinterpret_cast` it would be *fragile* to say the least as the compiler can do constant folding and the `KEY` might become non-unique.

Additionally, you should *define* the static member variable `KEY` in your application.